# how to limit search of files to only specific extensions

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-extension

I have one basic question (#1 below) and a question for which I have no idea (#2) about the answer. Can anyone provide inputs?

1.How to limit the search to only specific `extensions`,lets say to only `.c`,`.h`,`.cpp`

2.How to make the dot `"."` before the `"\n"` in `usertring` variable below optional

```
userstring="Copyright (c) 2012 Company, Inc.\nAll Rights Reserved.\nCompany Confidential and Proprietary." variable

import os
import sys
import fnmatch
userstring="Copyright (c) 2012 Company, Inc.\nAll Rights Reserved.\nCompany Confidential and Proprietary."
print len(sys.argv)
print sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit('Usage: python.py <build directory>')
for r,d,f in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for files in f:
        userlines = userstring.split('\n') # Separate the string into lines
        if files.endswith("." + c) or files.endswith("." + cpp):
            with open(os.path.join(r, files), "r") as file:
                match = 0
                for line in file:
                    if userlines[match] in line.strip('\n\r .'): # Check if the line at index `m` is in the user lines
                        match += 1 # Next time check the following line
                    elif match > 0: # If there was no match, reset the counter
                        match = 0
                    if match >= len(userlines): # If 3 consecutive lines match, then you found a match
                        break
                if match != len(userlines): # You found a match
                    print files
```

Compilation error:-

```
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    if files.endswith("." + c) or files.endswith("." + cpp):
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Comment: take a look at the `glob` module.

Comment: not sure the code indentation in your question is OK.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - am using endswith based on below suggestion but running into compilation error

Comment: Please *listen* to the error/exception messages. While there are better ways to do this search, the error has nothing to do with the title and little to do with the code (except that it happens to be part of it). Here is a minimal example to reproduce this error: `"oops!" + this_name_is_not_bound`.

Comment: @all - this thread is closed,thanks for all the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then `fnmatch` module is used to test filenames against a pattern match.

A regular expression can help match variations in what you are searching for.

```
import os
import sys
import re
import fnmatch

# Build a match pattern with optional periods and any amount of whitespace
# between the sentences.
userstring = re.compile(r"Copyright \(c\) 2012 Company, Inc\.?\sAll Rights Reserved\.?\sCompany Confidential and Proprietary\.?")

print len(sys.argv)
print sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit('Usage: python.py <build directory>')
for path,dirs,files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for fname in files:
        # Test the filename for particular pattern matches.
        for pat in ['*.cpp','*.c','*.h']:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(fname,pat):
                fullname = os.path.join(path,fname)
                with open(fullname) as f:
                    # This expects the copyright to be in the first 1000 bytes
                    # of the data to speed up the search.
                    if userstring.search(f.read(1000)):
                        print fullname
```

Here's a file the above code will match:

```
blah
blah
Copyright (c) 2012 Company, Inc
All Rights Reserved.
Company Confidential and Proprietary.
blah
blah
blah
```

Comment: i actually want to print the files which doesnt match the pattern

Answer (score 0):

for question #1, you probably want to use os.path.splitext()

```
>>> os.path.splitext('/home/myfile.txt')
('/home/myfile', '.txt')
```

Comment: am using endswith based on below suggestion from steven but running into compilation error,so not sure what is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first problem:

If you want to find files that end with a certain extension you can always use the endswith() method on a str that contains the filename. For example something like this:

```
if filename.endswith("." + extension1) or filename.endswith("." + extension2)
```

filename would be a str like "foo.c" and extension1 would be another str like "c" and extension2 would be "cpp".

source: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith

Comment: i updated code based on your suggestion,running into compilation error,what is wrong?

Comment: The problem was that c and cpp were variables not string literals

Comment: Just put quotes around c and cpp